# Verify heat produced by flame using enthalpy of fomation

Tags: thermodynamics, enthalpy, heat, combustion

I'm simulating using a CFD solver a pure oxygen/methane flame. However, I doubt that the combustion model does not produce enough heat. The heat from reaction is defined by $S_h=-\sum_{j} \frac{h_j^0}{M_j}R_j $ with $h_f^0[J/kgmol]$ the enthalpy of formation, M$_j$ the molar mass and $R_j$ the reaction rate of species $j$. The integral of the heat is my simulation is around $50kW$.

I tried to calculate analytically the heat prodruced using the equilibrium equation $CH_4+2O_2\rightarrow 2H_2O+CO_2$. With the non-stochiometric molar flux $\dot{n_{CH4}}=0.9625mol/s$ and $\dot{n_{O2}}=1.059mol/s$ I know I should be able to calculate:
$\dot{n_{CH4}}h^0_{f,CH4}+\dot{n_{O_2}}h^0_{f,O_2}=\dot{n_{O_2}}h^0_{f,H_2O}+\frac{1}{2}\dot{n_{O_2}}h^0_{f,CO_2}+(\dot{n_{CH4}}-\frac{1}{2}\dot{n_{O_2}})h^0_{f,CH4}+\Delta H$.

There I'm getting $\Delta H\approx472kW$, which is a factor 10. Either my simulation is really wrong or my ethalpy calculation are nonsense...

Is this way of chemical calculation correct?

Comment: For formatting of chem/math formulas/expressions, use can use [MathJax with mhchem extension \ce{}](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here). Note that chemical formulas should use upright fonts, what is honoured by mhchem \ce{}.

Comment: Never heard about these formula ! Where are they coming from ?

Comment: Enthalpy equilibrium,https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_enthalpy_of_formation#Use_in_calculation_for_other_reactions

Comment: Your equation looks OK.  What values did you used for the heats of formation?

Comment: @ChetMiller, thanks good to know.
$ h_{CH4}=-73.4e3;J/mo$l
$h_{O_2}=-0;J/mol$
$h_{H2O}=-285.83e3;J/mol$
$h_{CO_2}=-393.5e3;J/mol$

I'm more and more certain that my simulation calculation is wrong.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the heat of formation of water vapor (rather than liquid water)?  I don't know whether that will change things much.